# Internet stopped working suddenly on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, dell, internet-connection

My laptop was running smoothly until yesterday. Today, I can't connect to the Internet at home anymore. I am only able to access the router, but no Internet access.

A have a Dell Latitude E6320 with Ubuntu 12.04. At my job, I don't have any problems connecting this laptop both via Wireless and Ethernet. At home, if I try connecting it through Windows, it does work fine. I even checked the MAC address and it's OK.

My other laptop, which also runs Ubuntu, is not facing this problem.

I have already tried to restart and downgrade `network-manager` package and its dependencies.

Can anyone help me please? I am afraid, I will have to reinstall everything.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the Network settings of the other Ubuntu Lap top
2. Make a note of all the settings in all the tab.
3. Create the same settings in the new Ubuntu Laptop.

See whether it works or not.

Connect to router from the old laptop and get all the router information

Make a note of that. And access the router from the new laptop and see each and every settings are correct or not

See in the new lap top the restrictred network drivers are installed and active in the new laptop or not.

Similar case happened to me. In my case I am able to connect wireless using Windows but not with Linux